# split the message into array

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
RadikalGenc.aspx?phonenumber=5552451245&message=ISTAN-ALL-123;Emly,Foz,Praia,Sol,Luna,Trabalha

string number = Request.QueryString["phonenumber"].ToString();
string textMessage = Request.QueryString["message"].ToString();
```

I need the textMessage splitted int array Like this:

ISTAN-ALL-123 -> *Presents Form name*
**The list below, presents the fiels name**

1. Emly
2. Foz
3. Praia
4. Sol
5. Luna
6. Trabalha

how can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
string[] messageArray = Request.QueryString["message"].Split(';');
string formName = messageArray[0];
string[] fieldArray = messageArray[1].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (assuming that you're sure that will always be the format and that none of the values will ever contain one of the separators (`;` or `,`):

```
textMessage.Split(';')[1].Split(',')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the message variable two times. The first time by `ISTAN-ALL-123;` which will get you `Emly,Foz,Praia,Sol,Luna,Trabalha` and then perform another split by `','`

[`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(VS.71).aspx)